# CakePHP fills in the password field on create new user failure

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting funny behavior with CakePHP in my register new user form. It's a pretty basic username, email and password form.

When the user types out and incomplete form it looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/fcpS5.png]

Of course creation of the new user fails because the password and email fields are empty. When the form errors are shown it looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/Za9C4.png]

I'm not sure why the password field is filled up with text magically. Shouldn't it be empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't name the input field 'password' in the view, but 'newPassword' for example. That gives you the opportunity to do validation on the not-hashed password (length, strength, ..) and hash it manually afterwards by using the callback beforeSave():

```
function beforeSave() {
    parent::beforeSave();
    if (isset($this->data[$this->name]['newPassword']) && !empty($this->data[$this->name]['newPassword']))
        $this->data[$this->name]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->name]['newPassword'], 'sha256', true);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like it's getting populated with the hash of the password.

your issue has something to do with the way Auth handles auto password hashing inside the $this->data object. i believe it's enabled by default, and a hack it may be, i solved this by setting $this->data['User']['password'] to an empty string at the end of the action in question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the password field is being prefilled with a `sha1($_POST['password'])`, of course as `$_POST['password']` contains nothing it's the same as doing `sha1('')`.

I'm not familiar with CakePHP but you should disable the preffiling on the `password` field, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the hashing of passwords by telling AuthComponent to use your User model for sourcing methods, such as hashing:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = $this->User;
```

You can then overwrite the method that is causing the problem and it will be used instead:

```
function hashPasswords($data) {
    // do nothing
    return $data;
}
```

Obviously the above will disable password hashing completely, but if you apply the correct conditions to this example you can prevent hashing only when needed.

Full details here: http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/demystifying-auth-features-in-cakephp-12/

Answer (score 2):

Even better than any of the solutions here (except for the information regarding validating a field that isn't linked to the Auth Component then moving the hashed data to the correct index manually - that is good advice ) is to let the View layer handle this.

Since you can't read the field anyways, and good practice is to not remember or autofill *** masked fields (passwords in this case) you should manually set the fields value to nothing in the View.

IE :

```
<?php
    ...
    echo $form->input( 'User.password', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'value' => ''
    ));
    ...
?>
```

This will ensure that even though the value in the data array is hashed that that hashed value will NOT be displayed in your field.